# Derivative of function with absolute value denominator?

Tags: limits, derivatives, fractions, absolute-value

I am trying to find the derivative of the following function using the definition of a derivative:
$$f(v)=\frac{v+4}{\lvert v+4\rvert}$$
I've already tried substituting $|v+4|$ with $\sqrt{(v+4)^2}$:
$$DQ=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{(v+h)+4}{\sqrt{((v+h)+4)^2}}-\frac{(v+4)}{\sqrt{(v+4)^2}}}{h}$$
$$DQ=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{(v+h+4)(\sqrt{(v+4)^2}) -(v+4)(\sqrt{((v+h)+4)^2})}{\sqrt{((v+h)+4)^2}*\sqrt{(v+4)^2}}}{h}$$

$$DQ=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(v\sqrt{(v+4)^2} + h\sqrt{(v+4)^2} + 4\sqrt{(v+4)^2} - v\sqrt{((v+h)+4)^2} -4\sqrt{((v+h)+4)^2})}{\sqrt{((v+h)+4)^2}*\sqrt{(v+4)^2}*h}$$
, but I can't seem to simplify it enough to the point where I can cancel out the $h$.

I do know that as h approaches 0, $\sqrt{(v+4+h)}$ approaches $\sqrt{v+4}$, so I thought that maybe I could simplify some of the square roots that way

$$DQ=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(v\sqrt{(v+4)^2} + h\sqrt{(v+4)^2} + 4\sqrt{(v+4)^2} - v\sqrt{(v+4)^2} -4\sqrt{(v+4)^2})}{\sqrt{(v+4)^2}*\sqrt{(v+4)^2}*h}$$

$$DQ=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(v\sqrt{(v+4)^2} - v\sqrt{(v+4)^2}+ 4\sqrt{(v+4)^2}  -4\sqrt{(v+4)^2} + h\sqrt{(v+4)^2} )}{(v+4)^2*h}$$

$$DQ=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h\sqrt{(v+4)^2}}{(v+4)^2*h}$$

$$DQ=\frac{\sqrt{(v+4)^2}}{(v+4)^2}$$

$$DQ=\frac{|v+4|}{(v+4)^2}$$

, but it's also kinda fishy to me since I haven't cancelled out h yet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: is it ```f(x)``` or ```f(v)```

Comment: since  ```f(x)=1``` for ```x>0 or x<0``` it is obvious the derivative is zero for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: It's f(v), sorry. Also, the original question was asking if it was differentiable at v = -4

Comment: Step away from the square roots :)  None of that will make this function differentiable (or even defined!) at $v=-4$.

Comment: If you are determined to make interesting substitutions involving square roots, you could try $\lvert u\rvert =\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\sqrt{\epsilon + u^{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

If a function is differentiable at $x=x_0$, then it is continuous at $x=x_0$. Now if your function was differentiable at $v=-4$ then it would imply it is also continuous. But we know the function is not continuous at $v=-4$, since left limit and right limit are different at $v=-4$.

Note that the left limit is -1 and the right limit is +1.

But if you are solely concerned "How to cancel out h in the limit"

Just take the case where $v>-4$, then you can remove the absolute value. Then do the same for $v<-4$